# Google+ Profile 403 after getting access token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am working on a project to get Google+ Profile Info using oAuth. I have tried a few different methods, and I continuingly get a 403 Forbidden Error Message when attempting to get Profile data.

Here is the code I am using to get the access token

```
     GoogleClient googleClient = new GoogleClient
    {
        ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerKey"],
        ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerSecret"]),
    };

    googleClient.RequestUserAuthorization(scope: new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" });

    IAuthorizationState authorization = googleClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();

    if (authorization != null && authorization.AccessToken != null)
    {
        WebRequest testREQ = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"] + "&access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken));
        WebResponse testRES = testREQ.GetResponse();
    }
```

The above code throws a 403 when the GetResponse() is called

I also have tried the Library used here

http://www.googleplustips.com/resources/3332-NET-Library-Google-APIs-released.aspx

using this code

```
    string profileId = "me";
    string apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"];
    // You can get an API Key here: https://code.google.com/apis/console#access

    GooglePlusAPIHelper apiHelper = new GooglePlusAPIHelper(profileId, apiKey);

    GPlusActivities activities = apiHelper.ListActivities("eJx9Uj1IAzEUfglXeuASxbWQRX");

    GPlusActivity activity = apiHelper.GetActivity("z13rvzzy2lmtj3p0a22md1c4nyrdufrxv04");

    GPlusActivities activities2 = apiHelper.SearchActivities("Windows 8");

    GPlusPerson person = apiHelper.GetPerson();

    GPlusPeople people = apiHelper.SearchPeople("windows 8 club");

    GPlusComments people2 = apiHelper.ListComments("z120yhh54qrbsn5tr22rtjbiqr3mh1qp504");

    GPlusComment comment = apiHelper.GetComment("2HOqDyvQVCrbz47vK_w9nSrRYnS");
```

This also throws a 403 Forbidden on the ListActivities() call

I am guessing this is related to some setup that I have failed to do on my part, but I do not know where that can be. I have all the Google+ Services selected in my API Console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would verify to make sure the APIKey you are using is a valid API key for your project, and the IP address your request is coming from is one that is listed as a valid server address for your Key.

Make sure you have set an API key from the API Console in the "API Access" section
[image: Simple API Access]

When you create the Server key, you need to provide the IP address(es) of your server and Google will verify the key comes from an authorized host:

[image: Configure Server Key for simple-test]

You've indicated that you were using a Browser key instead of a Server key. Browser keys are just meant to be used by JavaScript or other clients that run in the browser itself, not for server apps that may output their results to the browser.

If the error changes to a 401 error after you switch to using a Server APIKey (which you seem to suggest from your comments below), it might be that you're not using a current Auth Token from the client. Tokens expire after 60 minutes, so you need to make sure you are using a current one.

Comment: I am not using a Server Key but a Browser Key (it is a web app that gets the info). The referer for my Browser app is the full url of my page

I set up a server app with my machines IP and got a 401 Unauthorized, which would make sense since its a web call.

Let me know if you need more info

Comment: If this is a webapp that runs on a server (as opposed to javascript that runs on the client, which this doesn't appear to be), you need to use the Server APIKey. The question is not where the content is displayed, but where the program itself runs, and C# typically runs on the server. Using the wrong type of key would probably be consistent with a 403 error. I'm editing my questions to deal with the 401 Unauthorized question.